# Check if service is running prior to install using Puppet

Tags: bash, puppet, puppet-enterprise

I need to check if a service is already running before it installed using puppet.

My code is as following, but it is keep failing.

```
exec {  'bud_sh':
cwd      => '/working_dir/',
command  => "Some Command",
path     => '/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/bin',
provider => 'shell',
onlyif   => "test -f /path/to/shell/script/exist",
unless  =>  "`ps -eaf | grep service | grep -v grep | wc -l` -eq 3"
```

}

**Following is the Error Message.**

```
 Could not evaluate: /bin/sh: 3: command not found
```

Appreciate your time and consideration on this matter.

Comment: As an aside: this is not really a good way to check if a service is running in Puppet, and only in very unusual circumstances would you need to do this. Could you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: Actually I need to check if a service is already installed and running on a host before it is installed.

Comment: It looks like you're having Puppet execute a shell script to perform the installation.  Although that can work, I urge you to consider instead packaging up your service (as an RPM, DEB, or whatever is appropriate for your system), putting it in a suitable repository, and managing its installation via a `Package` resource.  Aside from being good practice administratively, this will get you the behavior you seem to want for no additional cost.

Answer (score 4):

This error message ...

> ```
> Could not evaluate: /bin/sh: 3: command not found
> ```

indicates that the shell tried to execute '3' as a command, and, unsurprisingly, did not find it.  The only plausible source of such an issue in the code you presented is your `Exec`'s `unless` command:

> ```
> unless  =>  "`ps -eaf | grep service | grep -v grep | wc -l` -eq 3"
> ```

When the command there is executed by the shell, it first executes

```
ps -eaf | grep service | grep -v grep | wc -l
```

in a subshell and captures its standard output.  That output is slightly cleaned up, and then substituted into the overall command to yield, apparently,

```
3 -eq 3
```

, which the shell then tries to execute as the command '3', with two arguments.  To instead evaluate that as a conditional expression, you need to present it as arguments to `test` or `[` or similar:

```
unless  =>  "test `ps -eaf | grep service | grep -v grep | wc -l` -eq 3"
```

Answer (score 2):

> unless  =>  "`ps -eaf | grep service | grep -v grep | wc -l` -eq 3"

Other issues aside, you have a syntax error: `-eq 3` is not a valid command. If you want to evaluate the output of a shell command in *sh*, you need to use a test construct. For example:

```
unless => '[ "$(ps -eaf | grep service | grep -v grep | wc -l)" -eq 3 ]'
```

On a broader level, the [*unless* statement](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_conditional.html#unless-statements) is looking for a truthy Boolean value. The test construct does that by providing its exit status. Write your statements with that in mind.

Comment: Thank you Todd, I used John's approach and it worked. I tested your solution in a lower environment and this also works for my initial requirement.